# How could we prove $b^n=a$, where $0<a<1$?

Tags: real-analysis

In the proof for this proposition, it is divided into 3 cases ($a=0$ which is trivial; $0<a<1$; and $a≥1$). I understood the proof provided for the case $a≥1$, but I'm having trouble trying to prove the case where $0<a<1$.

[image: Image: page 1]

[image: Image: page 2]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I changed the title, gave more information in the description and pointed out in the screenshots what case I'm having problems with.

Answer (score 1):

If you accept that the proposition is proven for the first ($a=0$) and for the third ($1\leq a$) cases then given an $a$ with $0 < a < 1$, $\frac{1}{a} > 1$.  By the third case (already proven), there is a $b$ with $b^n = \frac{1}{a}$ so $\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^n = a$ and the second case is also true.